# Are there dress making Applications?

Tags: software-recommendation

There probably isn't but I envisage creating models of people and then dressing them with various clothes. Sort of virtual Barbie dress up.

Its hard to visualize patterns on clothes and would like to do it digitally if possible.

Can anyone give me some direction?

Comment: Do you have any examples of software that you may have used on another OS to compare to? Can you elaborate on what you are looking  for?

Comment: I think the desire is for the web-app type of thing that has been featured on the news recently with placing clothes or accessories on avatars built from the actual persons geometry to "demo" a product for a person.

Comment: I have never used one myself, see programs on TV where they click on people and dress them virtually like Second Life. That would be the closest type of program

Comment: @abrahamvanhelpsing any more details on that web app?

Comment: You're the one asking.  I saw it on the news, I don't remember the name of the company.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you might be seeking GNOMEKiSS, a fork of the KiSS project [here](http://www.otakuworld.com/kiss/).

Believe this is in the general Ubuntu app repositories and should be able to be installed, though can't say what version and there are probably non-free dependencies for actually using the software.